# Find which container uses a Docker Volume

Tags: docker

In running `docker volume ls` the response contains:

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               09033b4b22135832411ff485d5adc90e778316c1b9ba27bf8032cb65b8de557b
local               2ae85f4d2270716f936c4ef06e1a9408f90826258c7489a150125ff9d13ce79c
local               58497ac069495708d3bd17aab2b16b9a02badd245de4614a05a7133bdf0efb34
local               eb958485be4ae9c8a71a01a4f03c7cbf9f76c3a8fb2622ded58cf96542373b0d
local               efb5d345f272b32f409800e4804e22a93759c5668c8cb43e1887b5943ea217f9
```

How can I correlate those volume names to the containers using them?

I'm trying to understand where the volumes came from and if I can remove them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple example starting a `centos` container using a named volume

```
docker run --rm -dit -v my-vol:/my-vol centos
```

You can make use of the `--filter` flag to see which container(s) the volume is being used by<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
docker ps -a --filter volume=my-vol

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
0f70a651c472        centos              "/bin/bash"         24 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds                           distracted_swirles
```

If you want to remove volumes that are not being used by any containers, you can use **`docker volume prune`**

```
docker volume prune

WARNING! This will remove all local volumes not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

---

<sub>[1] https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering</sub>

<sub>[2] https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/</sub>